# Truncated logs in VSC, not showing all classes and uncovered lines

Tags: salesforcedx-cli, vs-code

I don't know what has changed in the sfdx CLI but for some reason it now prints truncated logs in VSC + it shows a false message that the test ran successfully but they failed.

To reproduce it, I open one of my test classes in VS, and click on the 'Run Test' button on top of my tests methods.

The result is truncated logs, which means that I don't see all my classes in the list (only a few) and also the uncovered lines have three dots "..." instead of specifying all lines, see below) :

```
=== Apex Code Coverage by Class
CLASSES                      PERCENT  UNCOVERED LINES  
───────────────────────────  ───────  ─────────────────
ActivityTriggerHandler       26%      2,21,22,24,25... 
TaskTrigger                  100%                      
ContactTrigger               100%                      
UserTriggerHandler           52%      15,16,28,37,38...
UserTrigger                  100%                      
AccountingTriggerHandler     42%      10,11,12,13,17...
AccountingTrigger            100%                      
PolicyBatch                  27%      14,15,21,22,23...
ContactTriggerHandler        26%      14,21,27,32,43...
ContactTrigger               100%                      
MemberHandler                45%      21,22,33,49,50...
MemberTrigger                100%       

           

11:13:33.955 Finished Run Apex Tests
```

I have more than 50 classes, but only 15~ appear ^.

Also, although the test method **fails**, VSC is showing that there was a successful run:
[image]

My cli version was sfdx-cli/7.84.2 but I read there was an [issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/811?fbclid=IwAR1W5cyyQE3GZfxg1IuRH1CUeMBhl7l-ncApy6Dcmmiln2JhGdsiWDma78k) with this version so I rolled back to sfdx-cli/7.83.0 but the issue persists.

However, when I type `sfdx force:apex:log:tail --color | grep USER_DEBUG`  in the terminal it prints the logs correctly, so it might be a VSC configuration?

I tried to restart my computer, uninstall the SF plugin extension for VSC, reinstall cli but nothing.

Please advise

Comment: The "success when failed" part [I've reported to Salesforce](https://twitter.com/brianmfear/status/1352680280859971584). I'm not sure about the other part, but have you tried using SFDX from the terminal to see if there's different behavior?

Comment: Yes, mentioned it in my post (3 rows from the bottom), in the terminal it works fine.
Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @sfdcfox for your comment.

Workaround:

> Preferences -> Settings -> *Type* 'Use Apex Library' ->
> *Uncheck*  **Use Apex Library for Apex CLI commands**